# Animate Maps using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I would like to know how can i make an animated ggplot map?
I'm trying to build an COVID Visualization over-time.

To show you some example, here's a code of my own:

#Mortes

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=ontem, aes(fill=deaths), color="#FEBF57", size=.15, show.legend = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "Mortes por COVID",size=8) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "BrBG",
                       name= "Mortes Confirmadas", limits=c(min(ontem$deaths),max(ontem$deaths)))+
  theme_void() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

options(scipen=10000)
```

This code returns this map:
[image]

I'd like to show the evolution of the COVID deaths over time. In the dataframe, there's a column named "date", which has the date time values like "2020-07-21".

Comment: There are many sources to help you. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60840971/creating-a-choropleth-map-with-us-county-level-data/60843261#60843261 and here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gganimate/gganimate.pdf#page=4 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155038/how-to-save-frames-of-gif-created-using-gganimate-package

Comment: i keep getting this Error: 
Error in transform_sf(all_frames, states[[i]], ease, nframes[i], !!id,  : 
  transformr is required to tween sf layers